# Alignment of form using Stylesheets

Tags: html, css

I want to design a application form using stylesheets. And later use it as classes in
 tag. 
I want to design the form this way

## Science-----------------------------------      Commerce

English,Physics, Chemistry----------------      English,Accounts

(------) is nothing but the space

Please Tel me how to use stylesheet for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a sample with  `css float`.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sbold sleft">Science</div>
<div class="sbold sright">Commerce</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.sbold{

    font-weight:bold;

}
.sleft
{
    float:left;

}
.sright{

    margin-left:200px;

}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MR6mb/1/)

this is the complete demo as you asked [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MR6mb/2/)

Comment: I dont want Commerce to be fully right.. I want it after some space after Science.                                                         Science-----------------------Commerce--------------------

Comment: ok..I want to use <div> tag instead of <Span>

Comment: now check my edited css and demo..!! let me know

Comment: @user3377635: tell me if you got what you asked..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the margin if you want to place "Commerce" at specific location. margin has the following syntax

```
margin-top:100px;
margin-bottom:100px;
margin-right:50px;
margin-left:50px;
```

It can differ in your case.

Hope this will help you.